# How to post event from adapter to activity using otto

Tags: android, adapter, otto

**Edited:** Don't suggest Interface, please.
I have an Activity with a RecyclerView inside. I want post an event from Adapter to Activity by otto, when Adapter will be created. I used following code: 
**ShoppingCardAdapter**

```
public class ShoppingCardAdapter extends  RecyclerView.Adapter<ShoppingCardAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private Activity activity;
private CardBook cardbook;

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    public TextView tvBookName;
    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        tvBookName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_book_name);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
                setTotalFactor();
    }

}

public ShoppingCardAdapter(Activity activity, Realm realm) {
    this.activity = activity;
    dataSet = realm.where(CardBook.class).equalTo("userId", userId).findAll();
    setTotalFactor();
}

@Override
public ShoppingCardAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                               int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.shopping_card_item, parent, false);
    ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
    return vh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    CardBook cardBook = dataSet.get(position);
    holder.tvBookName.setText(cardBook.getName());

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return dataSet.size();
}

private void setTotalFactor() {
    BusProvider.getInstance().post(new ShoppingCardBooksChangeEvent(dataSet.size(), String.valueOf(dataSet.sum("price"))));
}}
```

in **ShoppingCardActivity**

```
    @Subscribe
public void shoppingCardBooksChanged (ShoppingCardBooksChangeEvent shoppingCardBooksChangeEvent) {
    Log.i("OTTO TEST", "come on :)");
}
@Override protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    BusProvider.getInstance().register(this);
    checkBuyValidation();
}

@Override protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    BusProvider.getInstance().unregister(this);
}
```

why Log doesn't show up?

Comment: Means you want to call some method in activity from adapter? Is i understand your problem right?

Comment: Use callbacks(interface).

Comment: @Vivek Yes, I used otto becuase of that

Comment: @Ram I want otto :) not interface

Comment: I never used otto, I prefer Interfaces. But i have good tutorial for you. Hope it will help you. http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaLibrary-EventBusOtto/article.html

Comment: where in your activity you are registering to receive events ?

Comment: in the sample code from Otto, instance object will still need to register themselves, regardless whether they are just producing / subscribing / both to the events. So in your case, u will need your adapter to register its instance to the main Bus, maybe during the construction.

Answer (score 1):

Register your activity class to receive events like `BusProvider.getInstance().register(this);`

Comment: Thanks Shubhang..I have missed it

Answer (score 0):

```
"I want post an event from Adapter to Activity by otto, when Adapter will be created"
```

You are posting the event in the `onClick(View view)` method. So it will only post the event when that method is triggered. Move it out of this method if you want to post the event when the adapter is created.

Comment: Sorry about that, i missed it because of clean up code. I edited my code. please look at it again.

Comment: you are still posting the event in 'setTotalFactor()' which is triggered by the 'onclick' method. Move the event post method onto the Viewholder constructor.

Comment: After edit, I called setTotalFactor() in ShoppingCardAdapter constructor. am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

To post from the adapter: get a bus instance in the constructor and post.

To subscribe on the *Activity*: get a bus instance and register the activity on `onResume()` and unregister on `onPause()`.

To post from the *RecyclerView.ViewHolder*: get a bus instance in the *ViewHolder*'s constructor (or get it in the adapter's constructor) and post.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like it's a bit late, but here is my answer for anyone who faces this kind of problems, I think the mentioned

> ShoppingCardActivity

might be a base abstract class which registration of Otto bus in an abstract class has no effect, So you have to register and unregister in your outer activity which is not abstract, this is what I can say based on your code, If there's any more information please let us know

here is a comment from official documentation:

> Registering will only find methods on the immediate class type. Unlike the Guava event bus, Otto will not traverse the class hierarchy and add methods from base classes or interfaces that are annotated. This is an explicit design decision to improve performance of the library as well as keep your code simple and unambiguous.